# Is there a way, to install an SSH key with a limited lifetime?

Tags: bash, ssh, authorized-keys

I wrote a bash script to move some Apps (Redmine, Svn, Git, ..) from server A to server B.
At the beginning the script (running on A) installed an SSH key on B, so it could do ssh,scp etc. on server B, but asking me for a password only once.
Finally the script removes the SSH key from Server B like so:

```
ssh -i MyKey user@B "sed -i '/SPECIAL_TEXT_OF_MYKEY/d' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

OK - works for me (had to get around my `'cp -i'` alias, but that is another story).
*Here is my question:*
Is it possible, to get a key removed or at least invalidated from authorized_keys **automatically**
after some time period?  Something like:

```
ssh-copy-id --invalidate-after=60min -i MY_TEMP_KEY user@B
```

Comment: My guess is "Yes". I'm not sure if there is an _official_ way, but maybe you could use the `at` command? Not entirely sure, but that might help.

Comment: Thanks, but no, this is not what I'm looking for. Actually I'm already doing something like that:  when my A-script is complete (after 20min or so) it runs the
"deleter".  But what if the script crashes or if the cron is stopped or if whatever.
What I want:  the key should just not work any more after a certain time.  Maybe later some tool can recognize "expired" keys and clean them up.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You could put the `at` command first.

Comment: Are you sure you need to install the key on B? Can't you use key forwarding? That way the key only exists while you're connected from A to B.

Comment: @Barmar 1:  hmm - writing a bash script feels more like programming for me. Is it possible to _move_ a question to another list?

Comment: Writing a script is programming. Configuring the system to do something automatically is not.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the mods to migrate it.

Comment: @Barmar 2:  put the ````at``` or _key-forwarding_ -- thanks, but no need to think in this direction the whole script is working fine _and_ also the "finally-remove-the-key" is working well.   My question just appeared while I was doing that.    Is it possible to *give the key a VALIDATION-PERIOD* or so (like for an SSL-certificate) - either when I create the key or when I ssh-copy it?

Comment: And THAT is not a programming question, it's a question about configuring SSH. I'm pretty sure there's nothing like that.

Comment: Yes you can [**time-limit an `authorized_key` entry**](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#expiry-time=_timespec_) in OpenSSH 7.7 up but `ssh-copy-id` won't know how to set that so you'll have to either add a step afterwards, modify it, or replace it. This doesn't alter the key itself, so nothing prevents the client from connecting to B and increasing the time-limit or removing it entirely. (@Barmar)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I don't think he's installing `authorized_keys`. `ssh-copy-id` installs a key.

Comment: You might look at SSH's CA certificate support, btw; you can put limitations in a CA signature over a key.

Comment: @Barmar `ssh-copy-id` 'installs' a key precisely by adding it to `authorized_keys` on the server (if OpenSSH, as is the case here)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oops, I misread the documentation, I thought it was for copying public key files.

Answer (score 0):

It is not my answer but it answers my question ..
Thanks to @dave_thompson_085 and @Bramer I found this:
https://superuser.com/questions/1598311/

So it looks like, removing the key by hand|script|cron|at
is a good and at this time the only solution.
May be I can use the Comment-Field to improve this a little bit.

Comment: The fact that you found a duplicate on a different Stack Exchange site is a hint. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_; merely _using_ UNIX utilities (except in the context of writing code) is off-topic here.